# Emacs crashing - can't find emacs_backtrace.txt

Tags: microsoft-windows, debug, crash, backtrace

I've recently made significant changes to my emacs configuration, and now it's crashing every now and then (maybe every week or so). The only thing that I noticed about it is that it happens when I switch buffers with C-x b.

I get a dialog box with an option to produce a backtrace to the file emacs_backtrace.txt, supposedly on the current directory at the moment it crashed.

But I can't find that file, not on the emacs/bin/ directory, nor on the directory of the file that I was visiting was at the time of the crash...

I thought about bisecting init.el to find the culprit, but since the crash is so intermittent it's going to take a while. So I'm hoping to find some kind of clue on the backtrace.

But where is the file?

I'm on MS Windows with emacs 29.2.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Crashing.html

Comment: The above link says that the file is stored "in the current directory of the Emacs process". In my Linux system, I can check `/proc/<Emacs pid>/cwd` to find that it is my home directory, but YMMV. You can try searching the file system(s) for it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=12908

> It's always written in the current directory of the Emacs
> process, which is normally a single directory determined by what your
> desktop shortcut says.

> [the file is written] only if you click NO on the abort dialog.

> Emacs on Windows doesn't change its current
> directory from where it was started, so the backtrace will normally
> end up in the same directory for all invocations of Emacs on that
> machine by that user.)

> The main Emacs process doesn't
> invoke chdir on GNU or Unix either, unless you use the --chdir option.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, I'd expect `C-h v command-line-default-directory` to give the correct value on Windows (if it was always run the same way via a desktop icon).

Comment: Thanks! The file is not on the executable's directory, which is the same as the one on the shortcut, and also corresponds to the return of C-h v command-line-default-directory. After searching the entire disk, it appears that the file in not produced at all...